# modal popup displays different text depending on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

So I am attempting to have a modal popup that displays two messages depending on what the user types into the text box. I want the script to check whether the input contains one of two strings, either ME, or TN (as I am looking at doing a postcode checker).

no matter what i try I can't get the popup to display two messages depending on the input. I don't want the form to submit, I just want to grab the contents of what has been typed.

Here's a link to what I have so far (imagine the close icon is in the top right)..

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var formResult = $('#postcode-form')
    var postcodeMe = /^[me]+$/;

    $("#postcode-form").click(function () {
        if (formResult.val().indexOf(postcodeMe)) {
            $("#basic-modal-content").html("<h2>Yes it works</h2>")
        } else {
            $("#basic-modal-content").html("<h2>no its wrong</h2>")
        }
    });
});
```

http://www.muchmorecreative.co.uk/modal_test/basic-modal-testing-jquery-conditions/

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using $('#postcode-input').val() to get the value of the postal code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have tried these two but not happening, played around with it and found a solution..

```
$(document).ready(function() {



var formResult =  $('#postcode-input')

 $( "#postcode-button" ).click(function(e) {

 e.preventDefault();


 if ($('#postcode-input').val().indexOf("ME")!==-1 || $('#postcode- input').val().indexOf("me")!==-1 ){
// perform some task
 $( "#basic-modal-content").html("<h2>Yes it works</h2>")
  }

else {

$( "#basic-modal-content").html("<h2>no its wrong</h2>")    
}

 });
 });
```

Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


var formResult =  $('#postcode-form')
var postcodeMe= /^[me]+$/;

$( "#postcode-form" ).click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

if ($(this).val().contains(postcodeMe)){

    $( "#basic-modal-content").html("<h2>Yes it works</h2>")

}
    else {

    $( "#basic-modal-content").html("<h2>no its wrong</h2>")    
    }

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're setting formResult as a 'global' variable (sorta). It gets its value when the page loads and never changes. You should change your code to get the value when you actually need it, not immediately after page load.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var postcodeMe = /^[me]+$/;

    $("#postcode-form").click(function () {
        //move it to here so that you get the value INSIDE the click event
        var formResult = $('#postcode-form')

        if (formResult.val().indexOf(postcodeMe)) {
            $("#basic-modal-content").html("<h2>Yes it works</h2>")
        } else {
            $("#basic-modal-content").html("<h2>no its wrong</h2>")
        }
    });
});
```

A few other minor things to consider:

indexOf returns a number. You should probably do indexOf(postcodeMe) >= 0

You can look at index of [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/53xtt423%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)